# node.js: Preserve stack-trace in re-thrown error in bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace, bluebird

I'm in a situation where I would like to re-throw an error but preserve the original error's trace. In plain old synchronous javascript that can be done like this:

```
 try {
  processThings();
} catch (e) {
  const moreDetailedError = new Error("Couldn't process things due to: " + e.message);
  moreDetailedError.original = e;
  moreDetailedError.stack = moreDetailedError.stack + '\nCaused by:\n' + e.stack;

  throw moreDetailedError;
}

function processThings() {
  throw new Error('Internal error');
}
```

The resulting stack trace will look as follows:

```
Error: Couldn't process things due to: Internal error
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:8:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    [...]
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
Caused by:
Error: Internal error
    at processThings (test.js:16:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:6:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    [...]
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Which is pretty much exactly what I want. Now I want to be able to do the same across promise-chain continuations with bluebird. Here's the equivalent promise-based code (must run with `BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=1` to get long stack traces):

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.try(processThings).catch(e => {
  const moreDetailedError = new Error("Couldn't process things due to: " + e.message);
  moreDetailedError.original = e;
  moreDetailedError.stack = moreDetailedError.stack + '\nCaused by:\n' + e.stack;

  throw moreDetailedError;
});

function processThings() {
  throw new Error('Internal error');
}
```

However, bluebird seems to swallow my `Caused by` information and simply gives me the stack trace of just the `moreDetailedError` without the original:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Couldn't process things due to: Internal error
    at Promise.try.catch.e (test.js:6:29)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    [...]
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:5:12)
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    [...]
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Is there a way of getting the modified stack through bluebird to come out properly at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent the problem by simply attaching the stack of the original error to the `message` of the more detailed one, instead of manipulating its stack trace. Not really the solution I was looking for, but it works for my purposes.